# Rewrite Rule for subfolder instead of main website

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a htaccess code that i want to be changed.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ proxy.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works like a charm if i place `proxy.php` and `.htaccess` file in main website and visit pages through www.domain.com/

I want to change this `RewriteRule` in a way that if I place the `proxy.php` and `htaccess` in subfolder named "folder" then new results show in www.domain.com/folder/

So mainly purpose is to change results path from www.domain.com to www.domain.com/folder/

Comment: What have you tried so far? Wouldn't it just work if you move that code? Or what do you mean by "new results show in www.domain.com/folder/"?

Comment: i tried RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /fonts/

RewriteRule ^/fonts/(.*)$ proxy.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: I mean to say that this code is SET to work for website root, but i want it to work for subfolder so that if someone visits www.domain.com/folder/ the proxy.php result show here.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your code without any changes in `/folder/.htaccess` with `proxy.php`.
Or you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/(.+)$ folder/proxy.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```